# Can't figure out what is causing this Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in

Tags: php

The php file that I have has been starting to act up lately. It has been working for years up until just a month ago. I have looked everywhere and can not find anything that will fix this issue.

In the screenshot its the line that is circled that is throwing the error of

[image]

> Fatal Error: Call to a member function format() on non-object in .....php.

So if I change it

```
$recent_hire_date = date_format($employee['STRTDATE'],'Ymd');
```

I then later have to move down further in the PHP file and update each one that is like the one in circled line. However, when I run this php file (it generates a file), When looking at the data in the file it actually only shows 0 it does not show the correct data.

Comment: Any change in PHP version around the time the problem started (if so what was the old version and what's the current version in use)?

Comment: Please show us the code, and not a picture of the code

Comment: `var_dump($employee['STRTDATE']);`

Comment: `$employee['STRTDATE']` is obviously not a DateTime object

Comment: foreach($paychecks_array as $employ_id => $employee_paychecks) {

    if ($count % 1000 == 0) {
        $bh->start(1);
    }

    $employee = getEmployeeInfo($employ_id);

    // get last paycheck
    $last_paycheck     = $employee_paychecks[0];
    $last_check_date   = $last_paycheck['CHEKDATE']->format('Ymd');

    // determine facility code
    $facility_id = getFacilityId($last_paycheck);

    // start date in gp is most recent start date, because it gets overwritten with each placement
    $recent_hire_date   = $employee['STRTDATE']->format('Ymd');

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.4.3 I am not sure of the previous verison or if it was updated.